# JS Find pre-defined image

Tags: javascript, image, detection

Just looking for some direction (point me to the right library or terms, for example) not even sure what to call what I'm looking for:

I'd like a user to be able to upload an image of multiple avatars and the script to be able to determine which avatars were uploaded.

Working example - one image/screenshot that would contain 8 different avatars.  General location would always be the same (although exact position could vary depending on the capture method).  But, all avatars come from a predefined library. My script would then "read" the upload image, determine where the avatars are (they'll always be in a grid with a border) and compare those avatars to the predefined library and, ultimately, provide a list of all the avatars detected within the uploaded image.

I've glanced, briefly, at libraries like TensorFlow -but that seems to be overkill.  (Detecting things that look LIKE kites).  In my example, we'll have a library of identical avatars to compare against and they only variance in images will be image quality.

Thoughts on where to start research?  Is there a common term for this process?  A popular library that I could start reading about?  Just need a push in the right direction, please.

Comment: You're looking for [template matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching), probably using [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) or [SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features). Having said that, a google for "find image inside other image" would have probably led you to discover that on your own, and as a question for people to recommend you libraries/tutorials/etc this is explicitly an [off topic](/help/on-topic) question. The ball's back in your court.

Comment: That works for me. My search results kept leading me to tensoflow and AI stuff and it was late.  Thank you so much for the push.  I'm sure I can find resources from there.  Thank you!